# Run multiple git commands in a mean stack project using Bash script?

Tags: git, bash, github

We are using multiple branches (development, testing and master). Now the site is done with the most part of the application and bugs are solved. Everytime i have to push the changes on development branch from my local system and login onto server, go to the path and run these commands:

1. git checkout development
2. git pull origin development
3. git checkout testing
4. git merge origin development

Can we make these 4 commands into one?

EDIT: 
I created the bash script but how to add the pasword in the script ?

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "This is a shell script"  
git status
git pull origin development
```

?

Comment: you could just write a bash script?

Comment: yes, but what about passwords? How can i add them into the script ?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? I think if you use RSA keys you won't need a password. (If you want to script connecting to the server via SSH you could use 'sshpass')

Comment: Check this out https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html :)

Answer (score 0):

If you setup gitcredentials (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html) you should be able to script all of it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "This is a shell script"  
my_pass="awesomePassword"
server="awesomeServer"

sshpass -p $my_pass ssh $server "git status; git pull origin development; git checkout testing; git merge origin development"
```

(untested)
You will have to install sshpass and you should note that it is not really a good practice to hardcord passwords like that. Could be avoided by using user input.